# Error Vb.Net -Object reference

Tags: vb.net, object-reference

I have SQL2008R2 and it has data type of "bit" which has default value of "0". I have a option button for yes or no on the form (VS2012) and "No" is selected by default. I am getting this silly "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I try to insert the values into the table. This is what I have inside "try, catch, end try" block for the button.

```
Dim strPolice As String
strPolice = optPolice.SelectedValue.Trim()
If strPolice IsNot Nothing Then
PoliceDetailDS.InsertParameters("Police_Informed").DefaultValue = strPolice
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `optPolice.SelectedValue` is `Nothing`, hence theres nothing selected.

```
If optPolice.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim strPolice = optPolice.SelectedValue.Trim()
    PoliceDetailDS.InsertParameters("Police_Informed").DefaultValue = strPolice
End If
```

Comment: It could also be that `PoliceDetailDS.InsertParameters("Police_Informed")` is nothing...?  Shouldn't person asking narrow down possibilities through debugging?

Comment: @pseudocoder: Yes, the debugger works wonders in this case ;)

Comment: I tried both and get the same NullReferenceException error. With the break point I can see the value for strPolice is "True".

Comment: @Nita: Show us the code where you declare and initialize `PoliceDetailDS`, is that `null`?

Comment: I haven't declared or initialized it anywhere. This is my form:
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="optPolice" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>

Comment: Data type is bit and default value (0)

Comment: If you haven't declared or initialized (in vb code), you must have at least declared `PoliceDetailDS` in your markup (aspx file).  Please post the markup for that by editing your original question; don't post in comments since it's hard to read.

Comment: @Pseudocoder: I know I am struggling to format the code when I am adding the comment. I did not realize that I need to post in the original code. Thanks for the advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

```vb
If optPolice.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
    PoliceDetailDS.InsertParameters("Police_Informed").DefaultValue = optPolice.SelectedValue.Trim()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I did. I reconfigured the datasource and selected * instead of each field. then change the code for this way.

```
If optPolice.SelectedValue = "Yes" Then
   PoliceDetailDS.InsertParameters("Police_Informed").DefaultValue = True
Else
   PoliceDetailDS.InsertParameters("Police_Informed").DefaultValue = False
End If
```

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this will tell future readers much about what the original problem was or why your solution worked.

Comment: I don't know exactly. Had use the value True because the datatype was a boolean.

Comment: My guess is I had not specified "Police_Informed" field in the insert statment. Silly mistake.